# How to open a new tab in Playwright Java without any popup?

Tags: playwright, playwright-java

```
Page newTab = page.context().newPage();
```

this gives an exception PlaywrightException: Please use **browser.newContext()**

Comment: Try this: 
`try (Playwright playwright = Playwright.create()) {
            Browser browser = playwright.firefox().launch();
            BrowserContext context = browser.newContext();
            Page page = context.newPage();
            ....`

Comment: Hi I meant additional new tab @HosseinTaghizad

Comment: So you can simulate the keyboard shortcut for opening a new tab:`try (Playwright playwright = Playwright.create()) {
            Browser browser = playwright.firefox().launch();
            BrowserContext context = browser.newContext();
            Page page = context.newPage();

            // Open a new tab
            Keyboard keyboard = page.keyboard();
            keyboard.down("Control");
            keyboard.press("KeyT");
            keyboard.up("Control");
            // interact with it
           Page additionalTab = context.pages().get(1);  //2nd tab`

Comment: @HosseinTaghizad I posted an answer, This is just one step solution. Thanks for the good alternative solution.

Comment: Nice, does the posted solution work well for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can open new tab (not new window) using this

`Page newTab = page.context().newPage();`

but remember you initial Page should be opened with newContext() or else you will get a playwright exception like mentioned in the question.

`page = browser.newContext().newPage();`